# How can I redirect users but not Google (and other crawlers)?

Tags: php, redirect, search-engine

I want to redirect to a new page with a message just once to my visitors, but I don't want Google to think my content was moved permanently/temporarily.

How can I avoid this?

This is the PHP i'm using for the redirection:

```
<?php
@session_start();

$_SESSION['uri'] = $_SERVER['VBSEO_URI'];

function getRealIP() {

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

if(getRealIP()!=$_COOKIE['cookie']) {

    setcookie("cookie", getRealIP(), time() + 31536000, "/");
    header('Location: http://www.sie.com/redirect/');     

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

the solution i would use;

-Edit .htaccess add this line

```
RewriteRule robots\.txt robots.php
```

Create a robots.php file and paste in this code

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['robot'] = 1;
echo file_get_contents('robots.txt');
exit;
```

in your code... test this variable

```
                if (!(isset($_SESSION['robot'])))
                    {
    //this is probably human
                    } else
                    {
    //this is probably a crawler;
}
```

Create a session variable to test if you've visted and display message only once

Comment: That's a good idea, but I wonder if bots maintain the state between calls (to store session cookies)

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of good code out there to detect crawlers. Try [this tutorial](http://wanderr.com/jay/detect-crawlers-with-php-faster/2009/04/08/) to start.